# R: Meaning of "\" in Sapply?

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks something like this:

```
name = c("john", "john", "john", "alex","alex", "tim", "tim", "tim", "ralph", "ralph")
year = c(2010, 2011, 2012, 2011, 2012, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2014, 2016)
my_data = data.frame(name, year)

    name year
1   john 2010
2   john 2011
3   john 2012
4   alex 2011
5   alex 2012
6    tim 2010
7    tim 2011
8    tim 2012
9  ralph 2014
10 ralph 2016
```

I am trying to count the "number of rows with at least one missing (i.e. non-consecutive) year", for example:

```
# sample output

              year count
1       2014, 2016     1
```

In a previous question ([Counting Number of Unique Column Values Per Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74664615/counting-number-of-unique-column-values-per-group)), I received an answer - but when I tried to apply this answer, I got the following error:

```
agg <- aggregate(year ~ name, my_data, c)
agg <- agg$year[sapply(agg$year, \(y) any(diff(y) != 1))]
as.data.frame(table(sapply(agg, paste, collapse = ", ")))

Error: unexpected input .... " ... \"
```

I think this error might be due to the fact that I am using an older version of R.

Does anyone know if an alternate symbol can be used to replace "" in R that is supported by older versions of R?

Thanks!

Comment: Your R version may not be uptodate.  You can change `\(y)` to `function(y)`.  It is anonymous lambda function i.e. `agg$year[sapply(agg$year, \(y) any(diff(y) != 1))][[1]]#
[1] 2014 2016`

Comment: @ akrun  - when I try this code:

Comment: agg$year[sapply(agg$year, \(y) any(diff(y) != 1))][[1]]

Comment: I get the following error: Error in agg$year[sapply(agg$year, function(y) any(diff(y) != 1))][[1]] : 
  subscript out of bounds

Comment: Have I copied it wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Options if you can't upgrade your R version: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7833173/5325862

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `tidyverse`, we may do this as

```
library(dplyr)
my_data %>% 
 group_by(name) %>% 
 filter(any(diff(year) != 1)) %>%
 summarise(year = toString(year)) %>%
 count(year, name = 'count')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 1 × 2
  year       count
  <chr>      <int>
1 2014, 2016     1
```

---

The error in OP's code is based on the `R` version.  The lambda concise option (`\(x)` -> `function(x)`) is introduced only recently from versions R > 4.0

Comment: Inline functions were R 4.1, not 4.0 https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2021/000670.html

Comment: @ akrun: thank you for your answer! When I try your code - I get an empty output:

Comment: # A tibble: 0 x 2
# ... with 2 variables: year <chr>, count <int>

Comment: Is there something I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: @ camille: thank you for this link! I will check it out!

Comment: @stats_noob sorry, it is > R 4.0 and not >=

Comment: @stats_noob Regarding your comment about the tidyverse output, it would also relate to the R version you may have.  Please check your R version and update it to new version